# Turtle mouse event only responds after timeout, not as you click

Tags: python, while-loop, onclick, turtle-graphics

When clicking within the random squares, it says "You clicked!" only when it draws the next square, not when you initially click.

```
import turtle
import random
import time
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()

def turtle_set_up():
    t1.hideturtle()
    t2.hideturtle()
    t2.penup()
    s.tracer(1, 0)

def draw():
    for i in range(2):
        t1.fd(400)
        t1.lt(90)
        t1.fd(400)
        t1.lt(90)

def drawbox():
    t2.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        t2.fd(50)
        t2.lt(90)
        t2.fd(50)
        t2.lt(90)
    t2.penup()

def box1():
    X = random.randint(0, 350)
    Y = random.randint(0, 350)
    Xleft = X
    Xright = X + 50
    Ytop = Y + 50
    Ybottom = Y
    t2.goto(X, Y)
    drawbox()
```

Here is where it checks if your mouse click is within the box drawn. If it is, it erases the old box for a new one to be drawn every 3 seconds.

I don't understand why it waits to say "You clicked!" until the 3 seconds are up for the loop instead of saying it when you initially click.

I cant place a break command after the print statement that prints "You clicked!" because it's outside the loop.

between here:

```
    t_end = time.time() + 60 * 0.05
    while time.time() < t_end:
        def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
            X_click = x
            Y_click = y
            if Xright > X_click > Xleft and Ytop > Y_click > Ybottom:
                print('You clicked!')
        s.onclick(get_mouse_click_coor)
    t2.clear()
```

and here:

```
def starter():
    turtle_set_up()
    draw()
    while 1:
        box1()
starter()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're using `while time.time() < t_end` at all, but couldn't you simply take `s.onclick(get_mouse_click_coor)` out of that loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications with interactive GUI (Graphical User Interface) are event-based, which means that they perform their actions when some events happen. For such applications, if you create a waiting loop for a given amount of time (as does your code) the whole application will be blocked for this amount of time. That's why the `print` is only executed after the 3s delay.

All GUI libraries include a scheme to activate some timer events. For the turtle API, there is a `on_timer(func, delay)` method that calls a function `func` after some `delay` (expressed in milliseconds). The idea is to repeatedly call your `drawbox` function every 3000ms. So, your code will be based on two main callback functions: `get_mouse_click` called on click events, and `drawbox` called on timer events. Here is the modified code, I propose:

```
import turtle
import random

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()

def turtle_set_up():
    t1.hideturtle()
    t2.hideturtle()
    s.tracer(1, 0)
    s.onclick(get_mouse_click)   # define the 'click' event callback

def draw():
    for i in range(2):
        t1.fd(400)
        t1.lt(90)
        t1.fd(400)
        t1.lt(90)

def drawbox():
    global box                   # store box coordinates as global variable
    X = random.randint(0, 350)   # so that they are available for testing
    Y = random.randint(0, 350)   # in the mouse click callback
    box = (X, Y, X+50, Y+50)
    t2.clear()                   # clear previous box before drawing new one
    t2.penup()
    t2.goto(X, Y)
    t2.pendown()
    for i in range(2):
        t2.fd(50)
        t2.lt(90)
        t2.fd(50)
        t2.lt(90)
    s.ontimer(drawbox, 3000)     # define timer event callback

def get_mouse_click(x, y):
    if box[0] <= x <= box[2] and box[1] <= y <= box[3]:
        print('You clicked!')

def starter():
    turtle_set_up()
    draw()
    drawbox()

starter()
```

Answer (score 1):

Computers have to run in sequence so it can only process one line at a time, so, unless i'm mistaken, your program gets 'caught' on the timer then runs through the program and back to the start.
you could develop a while loop with a nested if statement that gets datetime from the device, if turtles have datetime

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify this problem.  Primarily by making a turtle ***be*** the inner box rather than ***drawing*** the inner box.  This simplifies drawing, erasing and event handling.  Avoid invoking the `tracer()` method until you have a working program as it only complicates debugging.  We can also ***stamp*** rather than ***draw*** the border.

If we simply want to be able to click on the inner box and have it randomly move to a new location:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

BORDER_SIZE = 400
BOX_SIZE = 50
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def move_box():
    x = randint(BOX_SIZE/2 - BORDER_SIZE/2, BORDER_SIZE/2 - BOX_SIZE/2)
    y = randint(BOX_SIZE/2 - BORDER_SIZE/2, BORDER_SIZE/2 - BOX_SIZE/2)

    turtle.goto(x, y)

def on_mouse_click(x, y):
    print("You clicked!")
    move_box()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
turtle.shapesize(BORDER_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.color('black', 'white')
turtle.stamp()

turtle.shapesize(BOX_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.onclick(on_mouse_click)
turtle.penup()
turtle.showturtle()

move_box()

screen.mainloop()
```

If we want to make the program more game-like and require the user to click on the inner box within 3 seconds of each move, or lose the game, then we can introduce the `ontimer()` event as @sciroccorics suggests:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

BORDER_SIZE = 400
BOX_SIZE = 50
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
CLICK_TIMEOUT = 3000  # milliseconds

def move_box():
    x = randint(BOX_SIZE/2 - BORDER_SIZE/2, BORDER_SIZE/2 - BOX_SIZE/2)
    y = randint(BOX_SIZE/2 - BORDER_SIZE/2, BORDER_SIZE/2 - BOX_SIZE/2)

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    screen.ontimer(non_mouse_click, CLICK_TIMEOUT)

def on_mouse_click(x, y):
    global semaphore

    print("You clicked!")
    semaphore += 1
    move_box()

def non_mouse_click():
    global semaphore

    semaphore -= 1

    if semaphore < 1:
        turtle.onclick(None)
        turtle.color('black')
        print("Game Over!")

screen = Screen()

semaphore = 1

turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
turtle.shapesize(BORDER_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.color('black', 'white')
turtle.stamp()

turtle.shapesize(BOX_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.onclick(on_mouse_click)
turtle.penup()
turtle.showturtle()

move_box()

screen.mainloop()
```